# what is the value of G used to normalize CMAccleration?

Tags: ios, accelerometer, core-motion

I'm trying to determine the user acceleration in m/s^2.

The documentation for the [`CMAcceleration`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Comparative_gravities_in_various_cities_around_the_world) datatype, as included as a field of `CMDeviceMotion` for example indicates that the acceleration values are measured in 'G's

> A G is a unit of gravitation force equal to that exerted by the earth’s gravitational field (9.81 m s−2).

'g' is not the same everywhere, [it can vary by some small fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth#Comparative_gravities_in_various_cities_around_the_world)-- but that fraction is significant when it's double integrated.

Are the values in `CMAcceleration` measured normalized by a fixed 9.81, or are they normalized by the value for gravity estimated by the CoreMotion fusion engine?

If it's the measured gravity, is there a place to access it?  The `gravity` field of `CMDeviceMotion` also appears to be normalized.

Comment: *"A CMDeviceMotion object provides both measurements in the gravity and userAcceleration properties"* sound like the gravity is measured as well - not fixed.

Comment: @luk2302, gravity is also normalized, so it reports values between zero and 1.